# AlloyUI Scheduler Event Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay, scheduler, alloy-ui

I'm using alloyui 2.0 scheduler http://alloyui.com/versions/2.0.x/ (with Liferay EE 6.2)

this is my scheduler :

```
  YUI().use('aui-scheduler', function(Y) {  
          var config = {
                    color: '#2bd434',
                    content: 'Prova!',
                    id: 'CUSTOM-ID',
                    disabled: true,
                    allDay: true
                }
                var Events = new Y.SchedulerEvent(config);
                var weekView = new Y.SchedulerWeekView();
                var scheduler =  new Y.Scheduler(
               {
                boundingBox: '#myScheduler',
                date: new Date(),
                items: [Events],
                render: true,
                views: [weekView]
               }
            )
    });
```

When I click on event, I want open another page with details of that specific event.

I have this listener on my scheduler :

```
 $("#myScheduler").on('click','.scheduler-event',function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var instance = this;
        console.log(e.currentTarget);
   });
```

I how can I set custom attributes on currentTarget?
If is not possible, can I set a custom id for that event?(so I can get the detail of this one)

Comment: I can't test what I'm saying now. Try `e.currentTarget.get('id')`

Comment: "[H]ow can I set custom attributes on currentTarget?" Can't you just do `e.currentTarget.set('customAttribute', customValue);`?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try `setAttribute()`.

Comment: I solved with a trick, posted here:
thank you all ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved doing this :

```
Y.Do.after(function(e) {
        $('.popover').hide();
        var evt = e.getData('scheduler-event');
            var id = evt.get('id');
            //Other attr created in events array
            var MYATTRIBUTE = evt.get('MYATTRIBUTE');
    }, eventRecorder, 'showPopover');
```